# How to test (sql developer unit tests) procedure with dbms_sql.date_table/dbms_sql.timestamp_table? Got error Invalid PL/SQL Index Table element type

Tags: unit-testing, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem with running Unit Test using Sql Developer for procedure containing e.g. dbms_sql.timestamp_table like:

```
create or replace procedure foo (p_arg_1 in dbms_sql.timestamp_table) is
begin
  null;
end;
/
```

I try to run test but I receive error (polish):

```
java.sql.SQLException: Niepoprawny typ elementu tabeli indeksu PL/SQL
```

By googling I translated it to:

```
ORA-1709: "Invalid PL/SQL Index Table element type."
```

Same problem for date_table but there is no errors for following:

```
dbms_sql.varchar2_table
dbms_sql.number_table
```

Is this a bug? Or am I doing something wrong? Theoretically Sql Developer interface is allowing to test such structures...

Comment: If your Oracle database is below Oracle 8i then `dbms_sql` is not avaialble. Check your oracle `version`.

Comment: Oracle database version is not a problem. I'm using 11g.

Comment: Also I'm making tests with utPLSQL and it is fine. But still it would be nice to have some GUI test interface.

Comment: For me its working fine. Not sure if your DB installation is fine or not